# Can this particular engineered wood flooring be floated?

Tags: engineered-flooring, tongue-and-groove

I am looking to install engineered wood flooring over a concrete and wooden subfloor. The flooring is 20mm, engineered wood with tongue and grove system. I am new to this so I have decided to go with floating method.

I am slightly concerned that the glue won't work on the particular floor that I have chosen. The manufacturer says it can be floated but when I look at it the tongue and grove the fit is very poor. There is literally no connection between these two boards; slight movement disconnects them.

The manufacturer has said:

> We would expect to see the T and G to look like this, if it is a super snug fit there is no space for the adhesive and this will be forced out when the flooring is knocked together.
> This way allows the adhesive to stay in the joint, dry and create a strong bond to hold the planks together while still allowing them to move with changes in temperature.

Common sense makes me thing that there isn't enough area for the glue to bind though.

[image]
[image]

For comparison this is a sample from other manufacturer. The fit is extremely tight on it's own:

[image]

Comment: Just a comment here, opinion based:  I think you will come to hate and despise the grooves between the boards.  They will be dirt catchers and hard to clean. Then you end up with a bunch of "stripes".   If you can possibly afford it and installation is doable (worried about the concrete portion), go with solid 3/4" wood of your choice, sand it down once installed (probably a job best left to a pro),, then finish with 3 coats of floor finish and you'll end up with a beautiful, smooth surface which can be re-finished many times when needed ....comment continued below:

Comment: The other suggestion I have is not to go with T&G, but "click together" sometimes called "snap together" manufactured flooring.  I've installed those several times and it turns out great.  They hold together with no groves to catch dirt.   Also, they are usually floated, so very easy to install.   Again, the above comment and this one are just my opinions, but to be honest, there's no way I'd used the T&G products you have pictured.

Comment: OK...I'm' going to blab on here a bit more.  My son just finished a new construction home and used his general contractor to install flooring, he went cheap and got a very inexpensive product. The general contractor (very small company), made several mistakes installing the flooring and now it squeaks everywhere when walking on it.   A call to the manufacturer of the flooring informed him that it was not installed according to directions and there was nothing they could do.   While more expensive, the best flooring I've installed is LVT, it's water proof, quiet,click together, easy to install.

Comment: Hello George,
So the floor of my selection - is actually quite expensive engineered wood flooring. I think I would like to go with it, but from opnions of others it might be best if I glue it down to the subfloor.

I absolutely value your opinion and they are absolutely valid. It's just I like this floor.

Is there any reason apart from the "grove" that puts you off these floors? 

I wonder whether I should glue them down to the subfloor.

Comment: @Taks   So much of this is opinion based.  Like my contractor said if a complained about something: " Well I can't see it from my house!"   He was kidding of course, we did have a good working relationship.    OK:  On to business: So many ppl in the trades say " I wouldn't done it that way" . Regarding gluing to the sub-floor, if you ever have to replace it, there will be Hell to pay tearing it up. If you're committed to the product and they need to be glued together, fine. Work with the manufacturer for advice.  Myself, I'd be reticent to glue it to the sub floor.

Comment: I agree: if you glue it to the subfloor, you do NOT want to be the poor soul who pulls it up later on.  I wonder if angle-nailing would do well in this case.  An angle-nailer will drive a flat nail at an angle into the upper inside edge of the groove.  You can rent pneumatic ones, and once you get the nailer tuned it goes pretty fast.  But it would only apply to the portion over subfloor, not concrete.  A better solution would be a different floor entirely, but I don't know if you are financially locked in to this one.

Comment: Although if you put down a layer (underlayment or what have you) between the wood and floor, gluing would be more of an option.  Still seems like an odd way of doing it, though.

Comment: Interesting :) This is a very expensive oak engineered wood floor, made to last. I am really surprised that people would offer click laminate or lvt..  Yes they are easy to install but that's about it. I noticed that most comments are from USA. I wonder whether there is a difference between how things are done in USA and in UK.

Comment: @Smith do you know of a pneumatic nailer that drives cut nails into concrete? To my knowledge most pneumatic nailers are designed to drive flooring nails through the floor into wooden joists/sub flooring, not into concrete.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not as concerned as others about the integrity of such a joint. With a good amount of quality wood glue there's a very strong bond formed between multiple faces there. Keep in mind that it's along a significant length that the joint occurs, and the total hold is quite strong. Not all joints are that poor anyway, so on average it's better that that worst-case example.

Here's my prediction for the actual outcome of a well-done joint. Green shows the location and approximate shape of the glue bond.

[image]

That's quite a bit of contact over the length of a run, and it's not like the floor flops up and down during use. Movement is miniscule and typically won't crack such joints.

Be sure each joint is well glued and tight on the surface. Use strap clamps for any challenging areas. It'll be fine.

Comment: Agree 100%. Further point: I'm not sure how tight flooring joints are supposed to be squeezed, but wood working joints, in general, are supposed to be clamped quite tight. This ends up with a glue line that is stronger than the wood around it (multiple tests show that the wood will fail on one side or the other, but not the glue itself). Maybe there's a special "wood flooring glue" that's to be used that doesn't require so much clamping force.

Answer (score 0):

The floor you've chosen really has a sloppy fit. I've done quite a bit of flooring and have not encountered T & G that fit so loosely. Any slight deviation in your sub floor will result in large gap in the finished floor. I'd think about going with another manufacturer or at least checking to see if you just got a bad sample.

Comment: Hi Jack,

That is why I am surprised why manufacturer says it's meant to be like that..

Comment: If I go with the first floor (which I quite frankly like a lot) do you think I should glue it down?

Comment: Hi JACK (not something I'd say on an airplane!  LOL), but I agree with you, they both look like crap. So are they saying you have to glue all that together?   What a time consuming mess.  IMHO a click-together floating floor is a superior product and easy to install.     Best of course is solid wood, sanded and finished in place, but that's pretty expensive. LVT (Luxury Vinyl Tile) is a great product, not cheap, but wow, does it stand up to wear and tear.

Comment: As @George Anderson suggested , think about  LVT.  You can get Luxury vinyl tile ( LVT) or Luxury Vinyl planks ( LVP)  that look amazingly like that wood and have less expense and easier install with better wear.

Comment: I agree with @GeorgeAnderson and RMDman  that there are better choices but to answer your question, I would not glue it down. Most manufacturers have never put down a floor. :-)

Comment: JACK - how about glue it to the subfloor using an adhesive? 

How would you "install" that floor? to concrete subfloor?

Comment: @Taks  You would need an underlayment.  If I was forced at gunpoint to glue it down, I'd get some Liquid Nails  because it good with large gaps and glue piece to piece.  The floor will still have to "float" so no adhesive to concrete.

Comment: If I was forced to glue it, I would put down a plastic-type underlayment and use a thinner wood glue (one that flows fairly well) applied along the top of the tongue.  You want the glue to spread around a bit and also to soak into the wood fibers, but don't apply so much that it burps out the top.

Answer (score 0):

That's a nail down floor if I ever saw one.... That's the only way I would set it in place. It is more stable that way, and you don't have to concern yourself the the other requirements needed for laying a floating floor.